# Load values for high Chart Values in jquery

Tags: java, highcharts

I am using eclipse tomcat 6. I have included highchart area graph in my project.
I have taken **area chart** from this tutorial  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-basic.
I want to populate the values of high chart in jquery function. I am calling servlet which fetches data from db. I want to populate the chart with data returned by servlet. How to do this?

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
              type: "post",
              url: "http://localhost:8080/RestDemo/rest/db",
              success: function(data) {
                  alert("Successss " + data);
              },
              error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 alert("error:" + errorThrown);
              },
              complete: function(request, textStatus) {
                 // alert("complete" + request.responseText);
                 alert("complete" + textStatus);
              }

           });

    chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4] );
    chart.series[1].setData([18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201] );

});

<button id="button">Set new data</button>
```

URL is DBConnection class which fetches data from database. I have implemented it as REST Service. I am getting method not allowed ERROR.

Comment: Read some tutorials, search a little, write some code. Then if you had a problem come here, this is not `write my code for me`!

Comment: I have tried and read some tutorials. but i could not achieve so nlyi have posted question here

Comment: Do you get `alert("Success")` after all? Or any of alerts?

Answer (score 0):

I removed Type="post".Now no error but it is either entering into success function and not to error function. But my restful service is invoked.